# does ubuntu have a program installer like windows msi?

Tags: software-installation

I am installing java on Ububtu 13.10. I know that there are 2 option to install jvm , manually or via apt command. But I am asking to myself, there is an ubuntu equivalent of windows msi or exe (I click and wizard do anything)?